# Why language is not regular

Tags: regular-languages, automata, finite-automata

Taken from site "Geeks For Geeks".
The lemma: "A concatenation of pattern(regular) and a non-pattern(not-regular) is also not regular language."

example: $\left \{L={a^{n}b^{2m}|n\geq 1,m\geq 1} \right \}$

I think I managed to build dfa (q2 is an accepting state) for language. perhaps I'm wrong... 
[image]

Comment: What are the two languages you are supposedly concatenating to obtain $L$?

Comment: Why don't you include the link to what you're quoting for context?

Comment: Your DFA does accept the language you call $L$, why do you think that is the concatenation of a regular and a non-regular language?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-identify-if-a-language-is-regular-or-not/ this is the link, check line number 5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you are absolutely right.  GeeksforGeeks is just wrong in this case.

Your analysis is correct.  The language $L=\{a^n b^{2m} \mid n \ge 1, m \ge 1\}$ certainly *is* regular.  Your DFA seems fine.  I don't know why the GeeksforGeeks article claims it is not; but in any case they are wrong.  It's a strange example; even by their own notions of what counts as a "regular pattern", $b^{2m}$ is a "regular pattern", so I don't know why they are giving that example.

Even if we try to look at better examples, the claim is still wrong.  For instance, consider the language

$$L = \{a^n a^p \mid n \ge 0, p \text{ is prime}\}.$$

This language is described by the concatenation of a "regular pattern" and a "non-regular pattern", so that article claims it should be not regular -- but they're wrong.  In fact, $L$ is regular, as $L  = \{a^m \mid m \ge 2\}$.

This whole notion of a "regular pattern" and "non-regular pattern" in that article is pretty much baloney.  I realize what they're trying to do -- they're trying to look for a shortcut to quickly tell whether a language is regular based on the syntax of the description of the language -- but those proposed rules are not a reliable way to tell whether a language is regular or not, and the notion of a "regular pattern" is not well-defined.  That's not a standard concept -- it's just something someone on the Internet made up.  At best, it is a way to form a quick guess at whether a language is regular or non-regular -- but I would recommend always following that up by proving your guess is correct, as their proposed rules are a bit dodgy.

Perhaps a lesson is to rely on primary sources, like well-regarded textbooks, and don't trust too much what you read on the Internet.

Comment: Small change: a^n a^p = a^m: m ≥ 2.

Comment: @gnasher729, oh yeah -- thanks!