# Proving the regularity of the following language

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

I have a question about the following problem:

> Prove that the language $\{a^nva^n | v \in \Sigma^*, n \ge 1\}$ is regular over
>   $\Sigma = \{a,b\}.$

I know that in proving a language is regular I can either construct a DFA, give a regular expression or show the Nerode-Relation has finite index.

My main problem is, that I cannot understand why this should be a regular language, since $\{a^nb^n | n \ge 1\}$ is not regular and of similar form. Also, I do not understand how a DFA should recognize the same amount of a's at the front and at the end of a word.

Comment: It doesn't have to make sure there are the same number of $a$ at both ends. Sufficient that there is one. Nothing says $v$ can't start or end with an $a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always take $n = 1$ for any string in your language...

Comment: I'd swear there's an old question related to this, but a cursory search didn't find it. Nice answer in any case.

Comment: @RickDecker The site is full of slight variants of these questions. I just [answered a similar one](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/120613/8311) earlier today.

Comment: Such "languages that look non-regular" are all over the place. Nice exercises to keep students on their toes *thinking* what the language is instead of just going by superficial characteristics like "there are some exponents in the description, so it's non-regular", or "words composed with some repeating parts, must be non-regular".

Comment: Shortly after I posted this question I had the same thought. If you are new to the topic of formal languages then such exercises cause you a headache. Anyway, thank you for your answer.